# Any help on placing buttons with Tkinter in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

**UPDATE** - I got it to work by using the `.grid()` function in Tkinter. Thanks for all the help!

I would like to make a button that will center itself in the middle of the GUI in Tkinter, but I have tried using the `place()` function and also, the `pack()` function will not work. Any tips or advice?

A section of my code:

```
restart = Button(tk, text = "Restart", command = restartGame)
    restart.pack()
    #The code to place the button in the middle goes here
```

Comment: So what happens? What does *"will not work"* mean?

Comment: The button does not center vertically.

Answer (score 2):

I rarely ever recommend using `place`, but if you literally only have a single widget that you want to put in the center of some other widget, `place` is a really good choice:

```
restart.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="center")
```

**relx** sets the relative x coordinate to be the middle (it is a floating point value between 0.0 and 1.0)

**rely** sets the relative y coordinate to be the middle

**anchor** specifies that the center of the widget should be at the x/y coordinate

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean centering the button at the middle of the top/bottom.

You can use `.pack(side = "bottom")` to place the button at the bottom (middle) of the Tk window.

Using `side =`, you can define it as top, bottom, left, or right.

So this means that your code would look like:

```
restart = Button(tk, text = "Restart", command = restartGame)
restart.pack(side = "bottom")
```

Comment: Ah. Thanks, but what I am looking for is to center the button vertically and horizontally relative to the entire GUI window, which is 500 in width and 400 in height. Any ideas?

Comment: @JoshDaBosh, In that case you would need to use place, as discribed in Bryan's answer.